# Error: Package: caddy-2.4.6-1.el9.x86_64 (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:group_caddy:caddy) Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, caddy

Am trying to get ssl working on my ec2 instance, but `sudo yum caddy install` tells me i need to have `Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)` which by the way i cant find a way to install it on linux ec2 server

Comment: If found any solution to this, please help us out :)

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: No, no success yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot download caddy package on yum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347341/cannot-download-caddy-package-on-yum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but was able to successfully install it by building it from source: https://caddyserver.com/docs/build#build-from-source

Make sure you have Golang installed first, that's really easy

Comment: No problem! Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.  I added some notes at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347341/

Comment: thanks @Levin Magruder the details you added about golang are so useful

Comment: this didnt work for me on the latest EC2 linux.

Comment: @Adam What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using binary file. Installing caddy via yum commands didn't work in my Amazon EC2 machine.

You can go to official github repo releases page of caddy, find desired version and download the binary.

```
 curl -sSLO "https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/releases/download/v2.7.6/caddy_2.7.6_linux_arm64.tar.gz"
 tar xvf caddy_2.7.6_linux_arm64.tar.gz
 echo $PATH
 sudo mv caddy /usr/bin/
```