# Cannot download caddy package on yum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, caddy

I using AWS EC2 on Amazon Linux and when i trying to download the caddy (yum install caddy) i have the following error. (shown on screenshot)

[image]

Comment: I had this issue and answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622285/514608 it only requires building caddy from source and downloading Go which is easy. Does that help?

Answer (score 10):

For me this recipe worked for Amazon Linux 2:

```bash
yum -y install yum-plugin-copr
yum -y copr enable @caddy/caddy epel-7-$(arch)
yum -y install caddy
```

Note the additional argument to `copr enable`!

[Here](http://www.asheiduk.de/post/install-caddy-on-amazon-linux-2/) is a little more background for debugging the issue.

Comment: i think this will work, let me try... i'll be back

Comment: I get Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit). I have a libc.so.6 in /usr/lib64

Comment: For those who have tried the above commands and still getting errors, try to remove the yum-plugin-copr and delete the cache by this commands: sudo yum clean packages > sudo yum clean headers > sudo yum clean metadata > sudo yum clean all

Answer (score 7):

Edit Nov 19 2022 - [A.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436450/514608) **worked for me, and is probably what you want.**  The solution I gave below works but is more complicated and takes 20 minutes; A.M.'s answer takes < 2 min to be up and running.

---

As of Oct 2022, you can build Caddy 2 without needing to know any golang.

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622285/514608. I give a bit more detail below, using a couple docs at caddyserver.org.  I ran this on Amazon Linux 2 Kernel 5.10 AMI 2.0.20220912.1 x86_64 HVM gp2.

The steps I give use "xcaddy".  The "go/bin/xcaddy build" command takes a long time, over 20 minutes for me.  I did the plain-old-build, without xcaddy, a few days ago.  Today, when I do it I am getting a security warning from go about bits not matching.  As described in the docs, if you don't use "xcaddy" the resulting caddy executable's "version" subcommand doesn't work.  With xcaddy it does.

## Steps

```bash
sudo yum install go -y

go install github.com/caddyserver/xcaddy/cmd/xcaddy@latest

go/bin/xcaddy build
./caddy version
sudo cp caddy /usr/bin
# /usr/bin is the path used in example systemd unit files from
# caddy server.org, so if you don't use this path, you'd edit those
caddy version

#  following: see https://caddyserver.com/docs/running

sudo groupadd --system caddy
sudo useradd --system \
    --gid caddy \
    --create-home \
    --home-dir /var/lib/caddy \
    --shell /usr/sbin/nologin \
    --comment "Caddy web server" \
    caddy
#  not shown but required: you create a file named  /etc/systemd/system/caddy.service
#  as per docs/running link above, use one of the two unit files
#  as a templat.  After which, if you are using a Caddyfile:

sudo mkdir /etc/caddy

#  And then create a Caddyfile in there at /etc/caddy/Caddyfile

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now caddy
systemctl status -l caddy
```

Comment: This didnt work. When i tried doing  go/bin/xcaddy build
-bash: go/bin/xcaddy: No such file or directory

Comment: @Adam, does `go install github.com/caddyserver/xcaddy/cmd/xcaddy@latest` complete without error?  Try again, I just cut-and-paste the commands into a fresh ec2 without problem.

Comment: @Adam, A.H gave another answer which is fast and for me it worked.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74436450/514608

Comment: this is currently failing with the following:

Comment: get"rsc.io/binaryregexp": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"rsc.io/binaryregexp", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/rsc/binaryregexp"} at //rsc.io/binaryregexp?go-get=1 go: github.com/caddyserver/certmagic@v0.17.2 requires
golang.org/x/tools@v0.1.6-0.20210726203631-07bc1bf47fb2: invalid version: git fetch --unshallow -f origin in /home/ec2-user/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/7d9b3b49b55db5b40e68a94007f21a05905d3fda866f685220de88f9c9bad98a: exit status 128:
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 944857 bytes)
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
[FATAL] exit status 1

Comment: @Bob I had that type of issue a few months ago and it went away few days later.